# Is it possible to change airports when using China's on-arrival transit visa scheme?

Tags: china, transit-visas, german-citizens

We are from Germany and we are going to Japan next year for holidays.
We are also planning to enter China because we are entitled to stay with a transit visa for 144 hours.

We will be entering Beijing and leaving Shanghai to Japan before our 144 hours visa expires. Is that possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is it possible to enter Beijing and exit through Shanghai airport?

NO, because first of all Beijing doesn't has a transit visa policy for 144 hours. Beijing only offer 72 hour-visa-free-transit policy. Further changing airport or leaving Beijing city is not permitted.

Source:[Beijing International Airport](http://en.bcia.com.cn/server/notice/72visafree/72visafree_policy.shtml)

"Beijing offers 72-hour visa-free transit for foreign visitors with third-country visas and transit at Beijing.
Foreign visitors, who hold passports issued by the countries on the 72-hour Visa-free Transit Policy List and stay in Beijing for transit for up to 72 hours, could apply for a visa-free transit stay in China at the immigration inspection authority at Beijing Capital International Airport. This policy is only applicable for foreign visitors who enter into, stay in and leave from Beijing."

Similarly the 144 hour transit stay is available only at Shanghai, Guangdong,Jiangsu, and  Zhejiang entry points. And while the 144 hour arrangement allows you to visit other cities in those regions, it does not allow travel as far as Beijing nor exit from a different region (ie can't come into Shanghai and leave Guangdong).

Source:[China Visa Exemption](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/intro2.htm#T)

As a German citizen you are entitled to stay in Beijing for transit upto 72 hours only with the following restrictions:

Source:[FAQ](http://en.bcia.com.cn/server/notice/72visafree/72visafree_faq.shtml)

- According to the policy, foreign visitors from the listed countries
  who plan to apply for 72-hour visa-free transit stay must hold a
  valid airline ticket bought before they enter into China.
- Beijing Capital International Airport is the ONLY entry-exit port in
  Beijing applicable for the 72-hour visa-free transit policy
- 72-hour visa-free transit foreign visitors are not permitted to leave
  Beijing to other Chinese cities during their 72-hour visa-free stay.
  Visitors who have to leave Beijing to other Chinese cities due to
  force majeure must apply for visas at Beijing Public Security Bureau.
- 72-hour visa-free transit foreign visitors are not permitted to leave
  the city where they get their visa-free transit stay permission

Further to your itinerary, you can always apply for a proper Chinese visa from China embassy/consulate from Germany or from your country of residence.

Comment: Ali types faster than me, so will simply add more to his answer ... the 144 hour transit stay is available only at Shanghai and Guangdong entry points.  And while the 144 hour arrangement allows you to visit other cities in those regions, it does not allow travel as far as Beijing nor exit from a different region (ie can't come into Shanghai and leave Guangdong).

Comment: @Tom adding tom comments into answer :)

Comment: Confirming this A and what @Tom says and to be clear, one is not even allowed to leave the respective zones with the 72/144h visa-free transit. +1